# Syncing multiple tables in MariaDB to Elasticsearch 7.5

Tags: elasticsearch, mariadb, kibana, elk

I'm trying to sync database to Elasticsearch using JDBC plugin but somehow this configuration is not working for multiple statements (multiple tables).

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => ""
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/DB"
    jdbc_user => "username"
    jdbc_password => "password"
    jdbc_paging_enabled => true
    tracking_column => "column1"
    use_column_value => true
    type => "type1"
    tracking_column_type => "numeric"
    schedule => "*/5 * * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_column) AS unix_ts_in_secs FROM table1 WHERE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_column) >= :sql_last_value) ORDER BY date_column ASC"
  }
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => ""
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/DB"
    jdbc_user => "username"
    jdbc_password => "password"
    jdbc_paging_enabled => true
    tracking_column => "column1"
    use_column_value => true
    type => "type2"
    tracking_column_type => "numeric"
    schedule => "*/5 * * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_column) AS unix_ts_in_secs FROM table2 WHERE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_column) >= :sql_last_value) ORDER BY date_column ASC"
  }
}
filter {
  mutate {
    copy => { "id" => "[@metadata][_id]"}
    remove_field => ["id", "@version", "unix_ts_in_secs"]
  }
}
 output {
  elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
      index => "test"
      document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
  }
}
```

This config running just fine for single statement but it's not working for multiple queries. What did I miss here? I need to sync this data to single index in Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by creating unique document_id